# channels without channel layer or any other free hosting

Tags: django, redis, channel, django-channels

I have a project in django 2.0 nad django-channlels 2.0 which I need to host I followed the documentation and I was able to run channels on localhost along with redis
but when I hosted on pythonanywhere,it showed it doesnot support websocket, so then I hosted on heroku,but there they were asking for verification of credit card info which i dont have to run redis.Are there additional hosting website whre I can rrun redis erver for free

Or is it poosible to implement channels without channel_layer and redis.My code is working perfectly fine on local host but can't host online for free.

```
class PageConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        self.accept()
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("admin", {"type": "analytics.admin_message", "message": "plus"})

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)("admin", {"type": "analytics.admin_message", "message": "minus"})
```

its corresponidng receiver

```
class ChatConsumer(WebsocketConsumer):
    def connect(self, **kwargs):
        self.accept()
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_add)("admin", self.channel_name)

    def disconnect(self, close_code):
        async_to_sync(self.channel_layer.group_discard)("admin", self.channel_name)

    def analytics_admin_message(self, something):
        if something["message"] == "plus":
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': "plus"
            }))

        else:
            self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
                'message': "minus"
            }))

    def receive(self, text_data):
        print("data hai bhyi", text_data)
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)
        message = text_data_json['message']

        self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'message': message
        }))
```

## settings.py

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [("127.0.0.1", 6379)],
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[from the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html)

> Channel layers are an entirely optional part of Channels as of version 2.0. If you don’t want to use them, just leave CHANNEL_LAYERS unset, or set it to the empty dict {}.

It will mean you will be unable to use `self.channel_layer` in the consumer, which you rely on.

So, it's optional but you need it.

[In memory exists](https://github.com/django/channels/blob/3d050a09eab994c675e01d48dad4f9b83c99e867/docs/topics/consumers.rst):

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS={
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
     }
}
```

Comment: yes I also tried that but after doing that i was unable to find out how should I send message how can I achieve the same functionality that I did above. like group_send,send,because self.channel_layer was returning None as far as I remember

Comment: exactly what is the use of channel layer?and why it can be set empty?

Comment: [read the docs](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html) to understand what it is and why it cannot be set to empty.

Comment: In short: you need channels layer config because you're using channels layer. In the same way you need database config of you're using a database.

Comment: Looks like in memory layer exists: `channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer`. consider if this is appropriate for your application.

Comment: awesome sir, thanks a lot, by the way can I ask how did you find this?

Comment: tough keywords(in memory layer) , thanks alot :-) was stuck since hours.

Comment: Glad to help :)

Comment: I know it's been almost a year, but is it possible to use [Memcached](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/cache/#memcached) to replace Redis, since it's already part of the Django's core cache framework? I know channels_redis interfaces with Redis and was wondering if something similar existed for Memcached. Grateful for any guidance on this.