# django channels on heroku hosting

Tags: python, django, django-channels

Since I cant use redis I used the other channel layer that is 
InMemoryChannelLayer

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_analytics.wsgi.application'
ASGI_APPLICATION = "django_analytics.routings.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
        },
    },
}
```

I deployed it, on heroku but I am getting error

> (index):9 WebSocket connection to
>   'wss://mkmnim.herokuapp.com/ws/chat/page/' failed: Error during
>   WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

I got it working at my local server but I am not able to do the same in hosting it online,Also will I have to do something related to daphne ?
Initially I used redis and ran redis server locally but while hosting redis setup was paid so I choose InMemoryChannelLayer 
([channels without channel layer or any other free hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53271407/channels-without-channel-layer-or-any-other-free-hosting))

so what should I do ?

## django_analytics.routings.py

```
from channels.auth import AuthMiddlewareStack
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from view_analytics import routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    # Empty for now (http->django views is added by default)
    'websocket': AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter(
            routing.websocket_urlpatterns
        )
    ),
})
```

## view_analytics.routings.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from . import consumers

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/chat/room/$', consumers.ChatConsumer),
    url(r'^ws/chat/page/$', consumers.PageConsumer),

]
```

## page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
    let chatSocket = new WebSocket(
        'wss://' + window.location.host +
        '/ws/chat/' + 'page' + '/');

    chatSocket.onmessage = function(e) {
        const data = JSON.parse(e.data);
        const message = data['message'];
        console.log("message is"+ message)
    };

    chatSocket.onclose = function(e) {
        console.error('Chat socket closed unexpectedly');
    };
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

edit 1:
added heroku logs as well

> 2018-11-13T08:12:14.240908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET
>   path="/view_analytics/page_check/" host=mkmnim.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=93802d36-fece-47b0-9e91-7f453d891f00 fwd="47.31.181.82"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=60ms status=200 bytes=726
>   protocol=https 2018-11-13T08:12:14.240275+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   10.41.198.116 - - [13/Nov/2018:08:12:14 +0000] "GET /view_analytics/page_check/ HTTP/1.1" 200 536 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11;
>   Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)
>   Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36" 2018-11-13T08:12:15.342043+00:00
>   heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/ws/chat/page/"
>   host=mkmnim.herokuapp.com
>   request_id=c2f225eb-1f88-4417-87fe-281b6dd6fd51 fwd="47.31.181.82"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=7ms status=404 bytes=2534
>   protocol=https 2018-11-13T08:12:15.340615+00:00 app[web.1]: Not Found:
>   /ws/chat/page/ 2018-11-13T08:12:15.341106+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   10.168.81.123 - - [13/Nov/2018:08:12:15 +0000] "GET /ws/chat/page/ HTTP/1.1" 404 2351 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81
>   Safari/537.36"

Comment: Can you show your frontend websocket Initialization code?

Comment: edited,added html :-)

Comment: Please clarify few details first. If this works in local then it will also works in `heroku` and it's nothing to do with `InMemoryChannelLayer`. 

Can you hard refresh your local browser and try to access the page in local server address?

Comment: yes its working in local server.

Comment: Okay. Please include the heroku logs if possible.

Comment: ya sure will be added in 2 or 3 minutes

Comment: I dont think I have done something related to daphne in local as well,is it required in online hosting att heroku?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183542/discussion-between-raja-simon-and-nimish-bansal).

Comment: Have you ever solved your problem? I have the same problem too...

Comment: Well I don't believe it will work in free version. You could try  setup in AWS free tier. And second InMemoryChannelLayer doesn't work in production, so you can use redis. https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1189