# Django Channel - Redis integration error : aioredis.errors.ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'EVAL'

Tags: django, redis, django-channels

I am new to Django channels and following the tutorial ( https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/part_2.html)

As Redis does not support Windows 7 I downloaded Redis version 2.4 from (https://github.com/dmajkic/redis/downloads)

When I try to access the Redis from Django shell I got error as mentioned in the subject.

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> import channels.layers
>>> channel_layer = channels.layers.get_channel_layer()
>>> from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)('test_channel', {'type': 'hello'})
>>> async_to_sync(channel_layer.receive)('test_channel')      # ERROR OCCURED AFTER THIS STEP
```

As you can see below, the Redis folder , it start dev server at port 6379.
[image]

Comment: [Eval](https://redis.io/commands/eval) is available since Redis 2.6. Redis 2.4 is close to 10 years old - it's kind of expected that modern frameworks have moved away from an unsupported platform and unsupported release.

Comment: Thank you, Do you have any reference for Redis 2.6 repo ?

Comment: Downloaded Redis 2.4 from (https://sourceforge.net/projects/redis/) :  but got new errorm ,aioredis.errors.ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'BZPOPMIN'.

Comment: @Melvyn Can I run Channels without Redis ?

Comment: https://github.com/django/channels_redis#dependencies -> Redis >= 5.0. You can run channels with an another [layers backend](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#in-memory-channel-layer) but the tutorial uses redis.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53271686/10515390

Comment: As @Melvyn says, channels_redis depends on redis 5. In my case I had just downloaded the win32 zip for redis, which was 3.x and threw the error you ask about. Using the docker image for redis v5 instead, as the tutorial instructed, resolved the error for me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem following the same tutorial, including a similar and older project that suddenly stopped working ... The following change solved my problem:

Before:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
       'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('127.0.0.1', 6379)]
        },
    },
}
```

Solution:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"
   }
}
```

Source: https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/channel_layers.html#in-memory-channel-layer

Comment: hey! thanks a lot.. I was also facing the same challenge for a long time.. and most of the time its just such trivial things!

Comment: Thanks so much dude, i have been trubleshooting this since morning before i came across your solution.

Thanks a bunch

Comment: You saved me. Thank you!

Comment: hey, I changed the layer settings earlier to `InMemoryChannelLayer` and it was working fine until recently. And I came across this [documentation](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/channel_layers.html#) which says not to use In memory config in production. So I'm back to `EVAL` error. Any other possible solution?

Comment: This is basically a non-solution given that `InMemoryChannelLayer` does not work for most production setups (i.e. any setup with more than a single server thread)

Comment: InMemoryChannelLayer is good for development purposes. i can't get redis channel layer to work at the moment, so I will use it. but ultimately needs to be switched to redis